# "Break" for loop in OCaml

Tags: arrays, for-loop, ocaml, break

I need to test all possible combinations in a 5 element array in OCaml, if any combination meets a condition, I must stop for loops and return that array, but is not easy return something in a for...

I have this code:

```
let myfunction t =
 let arraycolours = Array.make 5 W in
  try
   for i=0 to 3 do
    Array.set arraycolours 0 (inttocolour i);
    for j=0 to 3 do
     Array.set arraycolours 1 (inttocolour j);
     for k=0 to 3 do
      Array.set arraycolours 2 (inttocolour k);
      for l=0 to 3 do
       Array.set arraycolours 3 (inttocolour l);
       for m=0 to 3 do
        Array.set arraycolours 4 (inttocolour m);
        if test arraycolours = t then raise Exit
       done
      done
     done
    done
   done
  with Exit -> arraycolours;;
```

But there says:
Error: This expression has type colour array
       but an expression was expected of type unit

How can I return the array that meets condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's collapse your complex function definition by substituting your big for loop with the `<big-for-loop>` term.

```
let myfunction t =
 let arraycolours = Array.make 5 W in
  try
    <big-for-loop>
  with Exit -> arraycolours
```

The `<big-for-loop>` is actualy an expression, whose value `()` has type unit. The `try/with` expression, has the following syntax:

```
  try e1 with exn -> e2
```

Both `e1` and `e2` must return values of the same type. In you case the `<big-for-loop>` expression returns a value of type `unit` and the expression under the `with` clause has type `colour array`. This basically means, that depending on whether you were able to find a combination or not, your function will have different types. But types in OCaml can't depend on the runtime values, so we have a type error.

There are different solutions, depending on what you trying to implement, for example, you can raise `Not_found` exception if a combination wasn't found, e.g.,

```
let myfunction t =
 let arraycolours = Array.make 5 W in
  try
    <big-for-loop>;
    raise Not_found
  with Exit -> arraycolours
```

Alternatively, you can wrap the result into option type, and return `Some array` if the combination is found, and `None` otherwise:

```
let myfunction t =
 let arraycolours = Array.make 5 W in
  try
    <big-for-loop>;
    None
  with Exit -> Some arraycolours
```

I, personally, would prefer the latter solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should define a new exception type :

```
exception ExitArray of <type of arraycolor> (* may be "int array" in your case *)
```

Then, when you want to exit from your loops : you raise an exception 
`raise ExitArray  arraycolors` , at the end you  catch the exception and collect the result:

```
  with Exit a -> a;;
```

Comment: It does not work, I have done "exception ExitArray of colour array;;" and then "raise (ExitArray arraycolores)" and finally, "with ExitArray arraycolores-> arraycolores;;" but it still says "Error: This expression has type colour array
       but an expression was expected of type unit"

Comment: isn't it related to the fact that the if construct does not have the else branch ? you should add it : else arraycolours - that way there will no not more mismatch between the result prrovided by the lop constructs (which is unit in your current code), and the exception catch.

Comment: I dont think so, I have put an else with the same (raise (ExitArray arraycolores)) just for testing an it says the same

Comment: the point is that your function does not return the same type - this is what ocaml is telling you. When you raise an exception, your function return an array. Now, what is the type of the result when your function does not raise the exception ?

Comment: You are right, I have added '; arraycolores' to the last 'done' and now it's ok. Thank you very much Pierre!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that both the body of the `try` statement needs to return a value of the same type as the `with` clause. However, in your example, the body has type unit and the `with` clause type `colour array` (or something like that).

What you have to do depends on whether reaching the end of the loop should yield a result or an error.

If it should yield a result, there are two options you have. First, you can simply add `; arraycolours` after the last `done` to return the array. Second, you can instead use `; raise Exit` after the last `done`.

If reaching the end of the loop would be an error, you should instead raise a different exception, e.g. `; failwith "this cannot happen"` after the final `done`.

Comment: Another possibility would be to return `None` if no appropriate arrays are found and `Some arraycolors` otherwise.

Comment: Wooow, very thanks, it works!! @hugomg it will never return None, there will be always a valid array, so that it is not necessary

Comment: Then I would add `assert false` at the end of the loops so it makes it clear that reaching that point should never happen.  `Assert_failure` is also less likely to be unwittingly caught than `Failure`.